# Prevent submit on Enter but allow Enter for newLine in TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf

Is it possible to prevent the enter key from submitting forms, but allowing the enter key to work inside input. (E.g. `textArea` newline)?

I tried so far:

- `e.preventDefault()`
- `e.stopPropagation()`

Both on the form tag `onkeyup="if (e.keyCode == 13))"`

This does prevent submission of the form on enter key, but it also prevents the enter key from working inside formfields completely.
What I want to achieve is, that when I press the enter key inside a TextArea, that it creates a newLine but when I hit enter in a `input type="text"`that it doesn't submit the form.

Using JSF 2.3

JQuery solution is also ok.

Comment: Without the code, it will be difficult to help you out but I suspect you bind the event listener to the form as you only have to bind it to the inputs you want to actually listen

Comment: @3Dos yes I bind the event listener to the whole form. Otherwise I would have to add a listener to every `input` tag individually which I would not like to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test if the element focused is not your `textarea` like following :

```js
var area = document.getElementById('area');

document.getElementById('doesntSubmit').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.target !== area) {
    e.preventDefault();  
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="doesntSubmit">
  <input type="text" value="whatever"/>
  <textarea id="area"></textarea>
</form>
```

Or you could add a `data-` tag to the elements you don't want to be affected, or a specific class, ... to avoid checking for the tag.

You could also add a css `class` to the elements which shouldn't submit the form on enter and bind an event handler on it :

```js
$('.doesntSubmit').keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="doesntSubmit" value="whatever"/>
  <textarea id="area"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, this should work I think, but if possible I would like to not check for the tag. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

Get keypress event then check if specialClass is not :focus and check the pressed key (13 = Enter key)

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(!$(".specialClass").is(":focus")){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.which == 13) {
        console.log('You pressed enter!');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <textarea name="text" class="specialClass">Text</textarea><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

try below code:

```
if(event.keyCode === 13 && event.target.type !== 'textarea') {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
```